# Jquery Slideshow in page not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I am trying to integrate a jquery slideshow, but its doesn't work. I am using 3 files jquery, jquery cycle plugin and slideshow stylesheet, both are included in page but slidesow is not moving. Here is the link, the slideshow is in #slider ul .

http://tinyurl.com/88aotym

The relavant folder which has js and stylesheet is 'cat-slider'.

This is jquery function in the head section

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function() 
   {
    $(".slider ul")
    .cycle({
        prev:   '.slider .controls .prev', 
        next:   '.slider .controls .next',
        timeout: 3000,
        pager:   '.slider .controls .pages',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory,
        before: function(Ec, En, o, f) 
        {           
            var classTarget = $(Ec);
            var nextClassTarget = $(En);

            classTarget = classTarget.context.attributes.rel.value;
            nextClassTarget = nextClassTarget.context.attributes.rel.value;

            $('.slider .controls .' + classTarget).removeClass('selected');
            $('.slider .controls .' + nextClassTarget).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    // Pager Function
    function pagerFactory(idx, slide) 
    {
        var selected = (idx == 0 ? 'selected' : null);
        return '<img src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/cat- slider/images/blank.gif" width="13" height="14" class="number '+ selected + ' ' + parseInt(idx+1)+'" />';
    };
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show all of the corresponding code for your slideshow?

Comment: Having just taken a look I can't see the required .js being referenced on the page

Comment: Might want to address the 59 errors and 17 warnings (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Faxactsoft.com%2Ftest-2%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: @Amna Ahmed-Where is the easing plugin?

Comment: its not required for slideshow to work @coder , the slideshow can be seen at http://www.techmug.com/simple-jquery-slideshow-with-controls/

Answer (score 0):

I checked Your code with some breakpoints and as it turned out browser even don't jump into Your script code. Try change this:

```
$(function() 
   {
```

to this:

```
$(function() {
```

That's not a joke ;) I heard recently that in JS sometimes ';' are inserted automatically at the end of the line even if we don't want that in that place. Maybe it is happening in Your code.

Comment: Ok I see that You changed it and that didn't help. I'll look for other errors.

Comment: Can You modify code from $(function() { into $(function() { console.log($('.slider ul').size()); ?

Comment: Hmm, ok so I think that it's for 90% not a problem with cycle. It's problem with function. Can You try change $ sign to 'jQuery'? So start of Your code will look like this: jQuery(function() { Btw. is there any reason that You insert this code so high in DOM and not at the bottom of document?